# How to invert y-axis values on Python Notebook? Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter

```
fig = df.plot(x='base', y=['info1', 'info2'], template = 'plotly_white', title = "Title")
fig.update_xaxes(title_font=dict(size=18, family='Old Standard TT, serif', color='black'))
fig.update_yaxes(title_font=dict(size=18, family='Old Standard TT, serif', color='black'))
fig.update_layout(titlefont=dict(size =20, color='black', family='Old Standard TT, serif'))

fig.show()
```

How can I invert the axes so my lowest number appears at the top? This is not a linear graph

Comment: What is `df` here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse axis values when using plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643288/how-to-reverse-axis-values-when-using-plotly)

Comment: df is my dataframe

Comment: fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") is the answer