# Is there a way to rotate a plot in plotly javascript by degrees as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, plotly, plotly.js

I am working on developing a web server and I am using plotly-javascript to display my plots in results. I want my plot to be rotated by 180 degrees... say for ex: Right now my origin is in the left-hand bottom corner of the image and I want it to be shifted to the right-hand top corner of the image through rotation. Is there a way I can do this in Plotly-javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse axis values when using plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643288/how-to-reverse-axis-values-when-using-plotly)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.