# How to make all values on the axes positive or remove the minus sign on Plotly.Js chart?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I have a graph that renders some geometric configuration. And I would like all values (ticks) on the x-axis to be positive, even if the point values are negative. How can I achieve this?

My current axis configuration:
`

```
xaxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Position, m',
            },
            range: [axisMinX, axisMaxX],
            gridcolor: "rgb(229,229,229)",
            showgrid: true,
            showline: false,
            showticklabels: true,
            tickcolor: "rgb(127,127,127)",
            ticks: "outside",
            zeroline: false,
            autorange: "reversed"
        }
```

`

Also I found a suitable answer for Plotly Python ([answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61800485/15610075)). Is it possible to reproduce it in JS somehow?

Comment: Add `ticktext = list(x_ticks)` to xaxis where `x_ticks` are all the positive values you want.

Comment: The use of `ticktext` requires that you also set `tickvals`.  (Tick text is what you want to see; tick values are the actual values on the axis.)